# Why implement functions in records?

Tags: clojure, record

It is possible to implement protocols in records (and types for that matter). But, I'm wondering if there is any reason to do it if these specific functions would only be implemented once (ie. only for one record type) or if all the records use the same implementation of that specific function.

To illustrate, say I have a record for Player.

```clojure
(defrecord Player [x y hp inventory])
```

Now I'm given the opportunity to implement Update protocol;

```clojure
(defprotocol Update
  (update [this world]))

(defrecord Player [x y hp inventory]
  Update
  (update [this world] this))
```

Or, I could just write a separate function for this.

```clojure
(defn update [player world] player)
```

Is there any difference between the two, in efficiency or anything really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The simple function definition of `update` doesn't do a type check to make sure that you're only passing Players to it, but the protocol version of the definition does, and will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.  You might want this kind of type safety.  Or you might just want to communicate to others what kind of argument is expected, but there are other ways to do that.
- The protocol version is more verbose, adding complexity that might serve no purpose.  You might want the simplicity of the simple function definition.

I think that in the Clojure world, it's not uncommon to prefer simplicity of expression over type safety when there's a tradeoff between them, but it depends on the project and the programmer.  Personally, I usually want simpler code, but there are situations where I would lean in the other direction.

There are also these obvious considerations:

- The protocol version might confuse people, because protocols are usually used to allow polymorphic behavior, so they'd expect the protocol to be defined for multiple record types.
- If you expect to need polymorphism in the future, you might want to set up your code for that from the beginning by using protocols.

Finally:

- I don't have an answer concerning efficiency.  Someone else probably has something useful to say about that.  However, you could run tests using [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) to see whether there's a difference for your code.

Comment: If it has type safety, I want it. I'm not willing to use core.typed though as it seems just so verbose.

Answer (score 1):

This ought To be a comment to Mars' answer.

Regarding efficiency...
According to "The Joy of Clojure" 2nd ed. (Page 216 for the curious), calling a method with inline definition of protocol methods is several times faster than calling one on an object that implementes the protocol via extend.

Comment: I don't think it should be a comment.  It provides at least part of an answer to part of OP's questions (the part I couldn't answer).